# Function call stack: train_function error for model fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model-fitting

Function call stack: train_function error for model fit

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=10)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you train on CPU or GPU? Try to train on CPU to check if the problem persists

Comment: how to choose cpu or gpu

Comment: Do not post images of errors.

Answer (score 1):

[Function call stack: train_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315046/function-call-stack-train-function)

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

Add this code

Comment: Sir I got warning after this code  , and error inside coding shown in added image

Comment: C:\Users\legion\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py:1761: UserWarning: An interactive session is already active. This can cause out-of-memory errors in some cases. You must explicitly call `InteractiveSession.close()` to release resources held by the other session(s).
  warnings.warn('An interactive session is already active. This can '

Comment: The second error `OOM...` is due to insufficient RAM memory, so you should downscale the model or decrease the batch size.

Comment: The solution to the first error is to downgrade the tensorflow version. `pip install --upgrade tensorflowgpu==1.8.0` it seems to be a famous bug. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24828

Comment: @mero solved? try looking for more solution in Github if it didn't work or you shouldn't downgrade your TF version.

Comment: about OOM I don't understand how to downscale model and how to decrease batch size

Comment: OOM(out of memory) error is because your hardware is literally out of memory. By downscaling the model, I mean removing some layers and decreasing the number of channels in your model architecture. You can set the batch size by `model.fit(x,y,... batch_size=???)`.

Comment: If you are looking for a Machine Learning crash course, I personally recommend Andrew Ng's Machine Learning. It is free and I myself was highly engaged in the course.